# Call Rust Function(Copy_Dir) From Dart (Using ffi)

Tags: flutter, dart, rust, ffi

**When i am trying to Run this Function From Dart side it's always giving me this Problem**

memory allocation of 140374366121105 bytes failed
Lost connection to device.

**But my Source folder is only 2.4 kb**

**Here Is my Rust Function:-**

```
fn copy_dir(source: &Path, destination: &Path) -> io::Result<()> {
    if source.is_dir() {
        fs::create_dir_all(destination)?;
        for entry in fs::read_dir(source)? {
            let entry = entry?;
            let entry_path = entry.path();
            let dest_path = destination.join(entry.file_name());
            if entry_path.is_dir() {
                fs::create_dir_all( &entry_path).unwrap();
            } else {
                fs::copy(&entry_path, &dest_path)?;
            }
        }
    } else {
        fs::copy(source, destination)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

**From dart side i am calling this function like this:-**

```
`typedef CopyDirFunc = ffi.Void Function(
  ffi.Pointer<Utf8> source,
  ffi.Pointer<Utf8> destination,
);

typedef CopyDir = void Function(
  ffi.Pointer<Utf8> source,
  ffi.Pointer<Utf8> destination,
);

void main(){
final path = Platform.isWindows
              ? 'path\\to\\mylib.dll'
              : '/path/to/mylib.so';
          final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(path);
          final copyDirPointer =
              dylib.lookup<ffi.NativeFunction<CopyDirFunc>>('copy_dir');
          final copyDir = copyDirPointer.asFunction<CopyDir>();
          const source = '/path/from/ag_fsm_docs';
          ffi.Pointer<Utf8> utf8Pointer = source.toNativeUtf8();

          const destination = '/path/to/rust_play_folder/Jahid';
          ffi.Pointer<Utf8> utf8Pointer2 = destination.toNativeUtf8();

          copyDir(utf8Pointer, utf8Pointer2);

          calloc.free(utf8Pointer);
          calloc.free(utf8Pointer2);
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to unmangle the symbol and use C calling convention:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
extern fn copy_dir(source: *const u8, destination: *const u8) {…}
```

You’re also not supposed to use `Result`s and `Path`s in FFI.